# Merge two complex JSON objects (using jq)

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I'm trying to replace objects in a complex JSON object. It seemed that the tool `jq` could be offering the perfect solution, but I'm really struggling with the right choice / chain of filters.

I have a complete configuration JSON object which looks like this (has some more keys in it, shortened it for illustration):

```
{
    "some-array": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "attr": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo bar",
            "attr": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo bar baz",
            "attr": "value"
        }
    ],
    "some-other-array": []
}
```

Now I have another object containing an array with updated objects which I need to merge with the full configuration in some way. I need to find the nested objects by name, add it if it does not exist yet and replace it if it does exist.

```
{
    "some-array": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "attr": "new-value",
            "new-attrib": "new-value"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo bar",
            "attr": "new-value"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, with the above example, my expected result would be:

```
{
    "some-array": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "attr": "new-value",
            "new-attrib": "new-value"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo bar",
            "attr": "new-value"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo bar baz",
            "attr": "value"
        }
    ],
    "some-other-array": []
}
```

I already tried `select(."some-array"[].name == "foo")` to begin with and a few other things as a `jq` filter, but I'm struggling to move forward here and would really appreciate some inspiration / an actual solution.

Can anyone tell me if what I'm trying to achieve is actually possible with `jq` or do I have to find another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the updated problem.  This solution assumes that the names are string-valued.  It relies on two helper functions:

```
# array-to-hash
def a2h(f): reduce .[] as $x ({}; . + {($x | f): $x});

# hash-to-array
def h2a: . as $in | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ([]; . + [$in[$k]]);
```

The first of these creates a "hash" based on an input array, and the second implements the inverse operation.

With these helper functions, the solution can be written:

```
.["some-array"] |= (a2h(.name) + ($update|.["some-array"] | a2h(.name)) | h2a)
```

where `$update` is the "new" value.  This solution relies on the "right-dominance" of object-addition.

#### Output

For the given example, the output is:

```
{
  "some-array": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "attr": "new-value",
      "new-attrib": "new-value"
    },
    {
      "name": "foo bar",
      "attr": "new-value"
    },
    {
      "name": "foo bar baz",
      "attr": "value"
    }
  ],
  "some-other-array": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, and in fact quite easy under various interpretations of the problem as originally stated.

The following solves the the problem as it was originally stated, with "it" being interpreted as `.["some-array"]` rather than its constituents.

Assuming `$update` holds the object with the updated information as shown, the update could be performed using this filter:

```
.["some-array"] = ($update | .["some-array"])
```

There are many ways to endow `$update` with the desired value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer, but I can't get your solution to work. I tried `cat example.json | jq --slurpfile update example-update.json '.["some-array"] = ($update | .["some-array"])'` and I'm getting `jq: error (at <stdin>:17): Cannot index array with string "some-array"`. Does it have to do something with `--slurpfile`?

Comment: I tried `--argfile` instead of `--slurpfile` afterwards and that is getting really close to the solution, but instead of expanding `"some-array"` it actually replaced the content of the array, which is not what I want.

Comment: @zwerch - You wrote "add it if it does not exist yet and replace it if it does exist". Maybe you should show the expected result.  Regarding --slurpfile, please read the jq manual.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I appreciate your help and I added the expected result.